# Simulate multivariate normal when covariance matrix is not positive semi definite and has negative eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normal-distribution, matrix-decomposition, svd, simulation

Given a matrix $\Omega$ of size $m \times m$ that is not positive semi definite (some of the eigenvalues are negative) but symmetrical, I want to simulate $\pmb{Z} \sim N_{(m)}(\pmb{0}, \Omega)$. I tried first with the SVD such that $$ \Omega = U S V^T$$ but given that $\Omega$ has negative eigenvalues, I get that $U \neq V$, so setting $$\pmb{Z} = U S^{1/2}\pmb{X} $$ where $\pmb{X} \sim N_{(m)}(\pmb{0}, I_n)$ does not work. I also tried with the spectral decomposition, getting
$$
\Omega = Q \Lambda Q^{-1}
$$
but I cannot get $\Lambda^{1/2}$ without using complex numbers, and I am not sure that using a complex normal vector is appropriate. I have also attempted using certain algorithms that try to get a positive semidefinite matrix as close to $\Omega$ as possible (using Frobenius norm), but the matrix is not as close as expected. Finally, I also tried using
$$
D = \frac{1}{2}(\Omega + \Omega^T)
$$
and with $m = min(\text{eigen}(D))$ where $\text{eigen}(D)$ are the eigenvalues of $D$, establish
$$
\Omega^\prime = D +(\lambda-m)I_n
$$
and use $\Omega^\prime$ instead of $\Omega$, which successfully recovers the covariances, but the diagonal is overestimated by a factor of 4x, which is expected given that the procedure only ensures that the outer-diagonal elements are preserved.

My question is, ¿is this possible? And if it is, ¿how?

EDIT:

If it is not possible, ¿why not? Maybe that could give me a hint on how to proceed.

Comment: The covariance matrix is positive semidefinite not by choice but as a result of its definition.

Comment: I know, I want to know if I can bypass this restriction numerically, simulating normal variables with a certain structure not given by a covariance matrix. I know some packages just use the SVD when the matrix provided is not positive semi definite, but that does not recover the initial matrix.

Comment: Would you clarify what sort of "certain structure" you have in mind? Saying $Z \sim N(0, \Omega)$ has a certain meaning already, so for the slower folks like me take a moment to make clear what yours is. I take it $Z := \Omega G$, where $G \sim N(0, I)$ is not what you're after. It seems what you're fishing for is $\Omega^{1/2}$ for $\Omega$ with positive and negative eigenvalues, and if that's the case, it's probably fruitless.

Comment: Normal variables such that it replicates $\Omega$ not a covariance matrix; empirically, it contains covariances off the diagonal, but also covariances (all positive) in the diagonal, not variances. I am trying to solve a much bigger problem, which involves a covariance matrix of dimension in the millions. You can check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63817/generate-normally-distributed-random-numbers-with-non-positive-definite-covarian) the solutions I tried to implement, if it helps to clarify my question.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing how others can help you with this. In the meantime @jesús-piñera I wish you best of luck!

Comment: @Aruralreader Thank you very much!

Comment: You know that a millions-by-millions sample covariance can be a really bad estimator of the actual covariance matrix, right? Hence shrinkage estimators.